# AWS IAM or Linux Newuser to allow access to my Backend

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance, where the backend for my Mobile App is hosted.

My developer needs access to my server, in order to upload the new code and I guess test it also.

Now, I do not want to give him FTP details, so here is what I did:

- Created a new Linux User
- Created a new Key pair from the EC2 Console
- Created a .ssh directory
- Change the file permission to 700 (so only file owner can read/write/open the dir)
- Created authorised_keys with the touch command in the .ssh directory
- Changed the file permission to 600 (so only file owner can read/write the dir)
- Retrieved the public key for the keypair
- Add the public key in the authorised_keys

Now I can share the new generated PEM file with my Developer along with the username and my EC2 host IP address.

But I don't understand why not I can directly to this by creating an IAM User from the AWS Console and set his permission accordingly?

I am really confused because I first wanted to do it the IAM way but everyone suggested I go with Linux user - isn't it the same thing?

Also, I shall delete this user entirely once he is done with the work - right?

Furthermore, I don't understand something... after doing all this and setting up the new Linux user, I am able to connect to my server using the Linux Username and Unix Password only - without using the PEM file that I have created - how is that?

Also, technically that new Linux user can simply delete my main Linux user... I mean I can simply right-click on the User and press delete via Filezilla for e.g. How can I prevent this from happening? Even though that wouldn't matter, as he could also simply delete my entire backend?

I have the following on my server now:

**Home Folder**

- Home Folder > appBackend
- Home Folder > mainLinuxUser
- Home Folder > newLinuxUser

And last but not least, why is everyone always saying to never share the Private PEM file with anyone.. at the end of the day, if I only allowed specific IP address to connect to my EC2, then I should never be worried about anything? Same as I have done for my MongoDB - only if I add the IP address, only then that person can connect and view my Database. So with all the previous developers, I had shared my DB Configuration, it won't matter since their IP is not in my Security Group anymore - am I right?

Sorry, I am new to all this and I am trying to get my head around it all. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Creating Linux user vs IAM user :

IAM Users are for users who can access AWS resources based on permissions you provide. That means if you create IAM user with full access to EC2 and provide the details to your developer, he/she can login to AWS and have full access to EC2. He/She can create,start/stop, reboot, terminate your EC2 servers etc.
IAM Users/Groups are created to restrict access to AWS resources such as EC2, S3, VPC etc. and not for OS which runs inside EC2.

2. Yes, delete the user and keys once the work is done.
3. For login to linux sever, you can use either username-password or username-key. Check your user settings if you have set login with password. Use "--disabled-password" or similar when creating new user. Refer it here : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/
4. Check if you new user has root or sudo access. If you have provided sudo or root access, new linux user can execute such actions.

Note that, it is a best practice to delete the default root user on EC2 once server is up and running. ec2-user or ubuntu. Reason being, if your pem key which you had used when creating EC2 is compromised, your server is compromised. These default root users are known to everyone unlike specific users you'll create. Hence better to delete them.

Also follow the least access principle and provide only the least required access to new user. This means, you should create user as per the need or activity and restrict access to only that activity. Eg, if your user needs to only copy the files to/from within specific folders, set your user with a group and assign permissions to required folders. Do not provide any sudo access to it.

Similarly, you can create an admin user with access to sudo, however, make sure this user is not shared to other developers.

Comment: @saurahbh14292 Thanks for your answer. 

3. When I created the new linux User via Terminal it asked me for a UNIX password, I guess I should have skipped that and just pressed enter twice? Whats weird is that if I test and connect with my new user via Terminal using SSH and key pair, I am able to connect. If I try the same via Filezilla (also by using the Keypair) I am unable. Only when using the Username und UNIX password I am able to connect. But with my main ubuntu user, I am able to connect via Filezilla using my main key pair.

Comment: 4. I run sudo -v and received the following message:  Sorry, user Sam may not run sudo on ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx (<-- what IP is this?). 
So this user has no sudo access. 

I am confused about keypairs - I created a new keypair for my EC2 instance while creating the new user Sam (I guess this is the private key?). Shall I share this keypair with my developer now, so that he can log in to my server?

Comment: Why should I delete the ubuntu user? With what should I replace it with? The user I created above, what permission does he has if not sudo?

Comment: Edited the answer to answer your comments. Yes, you will need to provide newly created key to new user.

Comment: Can I simply delete the ubuntu user without having to back up anything or something like that? Isn't the ubuntu user linked to my online running OS?

Comment: What is the permission for only uploading files to a folder? @saurabh14292
I have already gone through the AWS Amazon link you shared... these are the steps in my initial question here

Comment: You have to make sure you create a new user with root/sudo access, have no process running by ubuntu user before you disable/delete ubuntu user.